# Stances vs Flurry of Blows

Tags: feats, monk, unarmed-combat, pathfinder-2e

I'm making a Goblin Monk with the background of being a poor farmhand at the sides of the monk.

My level 1 build would be to use Tiger Stance to deal 1d8+2 + potential 1d4 bleed.

When comparing to Flurry of blows, which is 1d6+2 twice if both blows hit

Is this a conflicting play?  I can use either approach to do *slightly* different damage, or can I use Tiger Stance with Flurry of blows - as Tiger Stance is still unarmed.  Which will do more damage?

Comment: I made the assumption that you want the best "damage dealing" as your approach.  Is that correct?  Are you trying to optimize for best damage output?

Comment: I guess it was a dual question. Can they be used together? If not, how do I optimise damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Tiger Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=436) gives you access to an unarmed strike while in the stance. [Flurry of blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=9) states that you make 2 unarmed strikes. Thus as long as you are already in the stance you can make 2 tiger stance unarmed strikes, rather than your default unarmed strikes.